# How should I properly leverage the form designer for JBPM?

Tags: jbpm

I have been learning more about JBPM, as I understand it there's the nice workbench which is geared toward the business process development, modeling and process oversight. However, it is not really intended for end users, correct?

So one of the neat features that's shown on the site is the form modeler (form designer) which gives the appearance of being able to quickly put together the relevant forms that would be facing end users (e.g.: human task owners) - from my understanding however, aren't we supposed to leverage the API and integrate it separately into our application? What is the purpose of the form modeler/designer?

Answer (score 1):

KIE Workbench is designed to be mostly used by developers, business analysts, and managers. Although it also allows end users to work on their tasks, it provides only very basic functionality in this area. It is expected that organizations build their own custom applications which make use of KIE Workbench remote APIs.

When it comes to reusing forms designed in the Form Modeler, you should take a look at section [13.5. Using forms on client applications](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch13.html#sect-formmodeler-UsingFormsclient) in the jBPM documentation. There is a description of JavaScript API which can be used to render forms you have modelled in the Form Modeler.